# wpf - viewmodel with two bindable collections. Use datacontext of one collection to filter the other one

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Long title, hope it makes sense. Can't seem to figure out how I would implement this. Or if my approach is even somewhat on track with best practices for this kinda stuff b/c i'm still working on mvvm and probably not using it correctly yet.

I have a simple viewmodel in an application i'm working on and it contains two properties which point to datamodel collections.

```
 public ChuteGroupsModel Groups { get; set; }
    public WaveStatusModel Waves { get; set; }
```

Each one of these datamodels contains all the data I need for a tabpage in my tabcontrol of my MainWindow. One tabpage is a grid of statistic data and the other page is a custom user control that visualizes a physical "working" area.

I decided today that I would like to display some of the statistic values from the grid (# of items, # remaining, etc) inside of the tooltips of my custom user controls. My two collections are only connected by an ID# field.

So, basically I need to figure out a way to filter/bind to my "Waves" collection according to the ID# property of the current element that is bound to "Groups".

The obvious easy answer here is to modify my sql view to include the additional fields which would make them immediately available for me to bind to in my application.

Since all of the data I wish to visualize already exists, I can't help but feel that changes to sql are a bit unnecessary and that some easy solution exists to help me gather these values out of my other collection.

Can anyone provide any suggestions of what I could attempt to do? If my question does not make sense I can try to re-state it with more code snippets and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some more information about your ViewModel / View binding would be helpful. As given, if your ViewModel exposes properties of both Groups and Waves to your View, and the View containing the TabControl is bound to your ViewModel, I see no reason why controls on either TabPage couldn't be bound to properties sourced from either data model.

To put it another way, the ViewModel can abstract away the separate data-model collections from the View, building, for example, its own collection of objects which expose the properties of both a `ChuteGroup` and its associated `WaveStatus`. The View can then be bound to that collection, and access the properties of both objects.